# strings.xml: How to remove underlining from the space preceding an <u> tag?

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

I have the following line in my `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="test_string">This is a <u>test</u></string>
```

In my activity xml I reference this string in a TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_string" />
```

Weirdly enough, when I run the app on my device (Xiaomi Mi A1, Android 8.0), the space preceding the `<u>` also gets underlined. Note the underlined space between "a" and "test" (screenshot from actual device):

[image: device]

I have also tried using the following in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="test_string">This is a&#032;<u>test</u></string>
```

But the result is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried SpannableString?

Comment: This worked quite well. I am new to Android development and have never used SpannableString before but thanks to your comment and some googling I was able to get it working. Also posted a detailed answer in case someone runs into a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on my emulator. To solve, I changed the string resource as follows:

```
<string name="underline">this is a &lt;u>test&lt;/u></string>
```

Then, rather than simply setting the string to my TextView, I ran it through `Html.fromHtml()` first:

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
String withMarkup = getString(R.string.underline);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(withMarkup));
```

Comment: Yep, this works. Actually, I prefer this solution to the one I came up with in my own answer using SpannableString. With your answer, you do not have to specify start and end character positions for each individual string. This makes it more useful in case you have several strings with underlining to deal with.

Comment: Note that fromHtml method is deprecated now. Now you have to use fromHtml method with fromHtml(String source, int flags) or fromHtml(String source, int flags, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler).

Answer (score 2):

Your string must be surrounded with the `"` character

```
<string name="test_string">"This is a <u>test</u>"</string>
```

It will avoid the underlined space preceding your `<u>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using SpannableString. Added the following to activity's Java code:

```
TextView testView = findViewById(R.id.test_view);
SpannableString testContent = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.test_string));
// underlining only "test" in "this is a test"
// note that 10 is the character BEFORE the first char we want to underline
// and 14 is the last char we want to underline
testContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 10, 14, 0);
testView.setText(testContent);
```

Obviously, in this example your TextView `id` in activity xml should be `test_view`.

This way, the space between "a" and "test" is not underlined.

Comment: This code works but only with that specific string. Indeed you specify start and end indexes based on that language. What if the occurence we need to set a bold style starts with another index in french, german, etc. ? A shift will occur

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with the XML character for space.

```xml
<string name="test_string">This is a&#160;<u>test</u></string>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE resources [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
    <resources>
        <string name="test_string">This is a&nbsp;<u>test</u></string>
    </resources>

Comment: The lack of newlines in comments is really unfortunate, but I didn't want to post a new answer just to point out that you can teach XML the character entity names from HTML.